# How is runq-sz counted in sar?

Tags: linux, kernel, cpu, sar

I would like to ask question about the output from `sar -q` . I appreciate if someone can help me out with understanding `runq-sz`.

I have a system which cpu threads are  `8 cpu threads` on `RHEL 7.2` .

```
[ywatanabe@host2 ~]$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l
8
```

Below is `sar -q`  result from my system but `runq-sz` seems to be **low** compared to `ldavg-1` .

```
                runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15   blocked
05:10:01 PM         0       361      0.29      1.68      2.14         0
05:11:01 PM         0       363      1.18      1.61      2.08         2
05:12:01 PM         0       363      7.03      3.15      2.58         1
05:13:01 PM         0       365      8.12      4.15      2.96         1
05:14:01 PM         3       371      7.40      4.64      3.20         1
05:15:01 PM         2       370      7.57      5.26      3.51         1
05:16:01 PM         0       366      8.42      5.90      3.84         1
05:17:01 PM         0       365      8.78      6.45      4.16         1
05:18:01 PM         0       363      7.05      6.40      4.28         2
05:19:02 PM         1       364      8.05      6.74      4.53         0
05:20:01 PM         0       367      7.96      6.96      4.74         1
05:21:01 PM         0       367      7.86      7.11      4.93         1
05:22:01 PM         1       366      7.84      7.31      5.14         0
```

From the `man sar` , I was thinking that `runq-sz` represents the number of tasks inside the run queue which states are [TASK_RUNNING](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lki/lki-2.html) which corresponds to R sate in `ps` .

```
          runq-sz
                 Run queue length (number of tasks waiting for run time).
```

What does `runq-sz` actually represent ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This man page has a more detailed explanation of this property:

> runq-sz
>
> The number of kernel threads in memory that are waiting for a CPU to run. Typically, this value should be less than 2. Consistently higher values mean that the system might be CPU-bound.

#### Interpreting results

As is the case with many "indicators" you have to use them in combination with one another to interpret if there's a performance issue or not. This particular indicator indicates if your system is starved for CPU time.

Whereas the load1,5,15 indicate processes that are in the run queue, but are being forced to wait for time to run. The load1,5,15 variety tells you the general trend of the system and if it's got a lot of processes waiting (ramping up load) vs. trending down. But processes can wait for a variety of things with load1,5,15, typically it's I/O that's blocking when you see high load1,5,15 times.

With runq-sz, you're waiting for time on a CPU.

#### References

- [How to Check Queue Activity (sar -q)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-0403/enuet/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

This post is the first that turns up in Google and the last answer above is ticked as being accepted.

The answer provides a reference of, and quotes the text of, a **Solaris** manpage. The OP's question was, however, regarding **RHEL 7**. The treatment of runnable process reporting in Solaris and Linux is different.

- Solaris tends to using load average / queue as an indicator of how many processes are waiting to run.
- Linux tends to using load average / queue as an indicator of how many processes are running + how many processes are waiting to run.
- The Linux representation of `runq-sz` in `sar -q` is more likely to indicate the number of current running processes + the number of queued processes.

To reference the OPs original example of an 8 thread instance, a `runq-sz` of less than 8 indicates optimal performance in this regard.

I would agree that the low `runq-sz` versus high `loadavg` probably indicates some sort of blocked or sleeping processes. You can partially see that in the OP's example sar output, in the `blocked` column.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:
uptime give you load average in last 1, 5, and 15 minutes. But not over period of time (like `sar`) with uptime you get momental snapshot of loads on the system.
And both (`sar` and `uptime`)reports the same information about load.

```
ldavg-1  -> last 1 minute
ldavg-5  -> last 5 minutes
ldavg-15 -> last 15 minutes.
```

`runq-sz`  is amount of processes that would need CPU/waiting for CPU

Correlated to the average load indeed (if there is high load then CPU starvation is possible) but not directly.

Waiting --> process waiting on some resource, this is not bounded (process cab wait very long time and therefore load average can be very high).

Queued process is one that in queue to get CPU, i.e. 100% waiting on CPU and will get some as soon CPU will be available, i.e. CPU starvation.

So from `sar -q` we can understand if we have CPU starvation (very high queue size).
From uptime and ldavg-# we can understand what the load on the system and may get a hint why queue size is high.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You say for Linux :

- load AVG = running processes + waiting processes
- runq-sz  = running processes + queued processes

That means that **load avg** and **runq-sz** include the running processes

So what is the difference between **waiting processes** and **queued processes** please?

For example can you interpret this please (the 1rst linewith runq-sz=10)?

This is for a 20cores(40threads) server

Does ldavg-1 > runq-sz means that lots of processes are waiting for resources (I/O for exemple) ?

```
06:10:01      runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15
06:20:02           10      1696     28.95     30.21     28.25
06:30:02            8      1672     25.93     27.57     27.78
06:40:02            8      1707     31.82     35.37     32.88
06:50:01            9      1707     28.90     31.06     31.89
```

the cpu usage of my server is low : 80% idle.

[image: cpu usage]

regards,

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/419761)

Comment: This is a question not an answer.

Comment: Delete and ask your question as a new question.